# Logger.warn from a controller in RAILs is not outputting the message in development.log

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

When I look at the development.log - I don't see my log comment. Please help.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    def vir_starttime
        Rails.logger.warn "sharad verma is logging"
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you showed. Post the part of your code that calls `Event#vir_starttime`.

Comment: yep -- the code in Event#vir_starttim was not being called.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would do it ;)

Comment: Probably you have incorrect log level.
There is answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180690/set-logging-levels-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  def vir_starttime
    puts "sharad verma is logging"
    # you also can use Rails.logger.info
  end
end
```