# Set logging levels in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I'm using following code to configure logging in my Ruby on Rails application:

environment.rb:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

class Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{timestamp.to_formatted_s(:db)} #{severity} #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

I'm trying to set the logging level to warn now using

```
config.log_level = :warn
```

in my production.rb, but it doens't seem to work. Am I missing something here?

If I put Rails.logger.level = 4 in my environment.rb, it does seem to work. But I would like to configure things in my environment initializers.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels), you should be using:

```
config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer, or
Rails.logger.level = 0 # at any time
```

If neither of those work for you, try:

```
config.log_level = Logger::WARN
```

And if that doesn't work, try:

```
config.logger.level = Logger::WARN
```

***Note:*** The final method appears to be conflating the two official strategies, but works in some situations

Answer (score 40):

For Rails 4.0 you can set the value in `production.rb` (or your desired environment) like so:

```
# Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
config.log_level = :warn
```

**Update** [The docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels) state it like so:

> #### 2.2 Log Levels
>
> When something is logged it's printed into the corresponding log if the log level of the message is equal or higher than the configured log level. If you want to know the current log level you can call the `Rails.logger.level` method.
>
> The available log levels are: `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`, and `:unknown`, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5 respectively. To change the default log level, use
>
> ```
> config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer, or
> Rails.logger.level = 0 # at any time
> ```
>
> This is useful when you want to log under development or staging, but you don't want to flood your production log with unnecessary information.
>
> > The default Rails log level is `info` in production mode and debug in development and test mode.

Comment: Just a note that "In Rails 5 the default value will be unified to `:debug` across all environments", so any other value would need to be set in production.rb as the answerer stated.

Comment: `config.log_level = :warn` works for Rails 3.2 as well.