# Showing only specific test case in test.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testunit

I am writing Rails tests using the standard Test::Unit/TestCase.

Is there any way to somehow filter what gets printed to the log, so that you only print the stack for specific test cases.

I have a functional test file with many test cases in it, and I'm really only interested in debugging one test case. Printing my own log statements still requires searching through a few thousand lines of generated log. Or something similar to the RSpec 'pending' functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run from a command line `ruby test/unit/my_model.rb` to run one test suite. You can also use a debugger, such as (wrapped by) RubyMine or pry, to stop on a specific test case and look at the log.

But if a sledge-hammer does not solve the problem, you can use tweezers: `config.logger.level = Logger::WARN` in your `test.rb`, from [Set logging levels in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180690/set-logging-levels-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Changing the log level works beautifully! I already do a lot of testing on single files only. This is great because i generally don't care about the log output of successful tests, and want to focus in on the ones that are failing. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better if instead of strangling the output to `log/test.log`, you become familiar with a command such as `grep`. Grep allows you to run very advanced search queries through files or directories, as long as your running on some flavor of *nix. The simplest use would be

```
grep search_term file_name
```

The reason I say you shouldn't constrict the log output is because someday that could bit you in the **s. Hope this helps.

Comment: These are the kind of solutions i'm using currently and it still takes too long. I want to go from 3 sec to find something, down to 1 sec.

Comment: If your tests fail too often, and you need to work too hard to figure out why, You Are Doing It Wrong(tm). See: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2012/10/git-reset-is-your-friend.html