# Logging in a Rails mailer receive method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, logging

In the [`#receive`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#receiving-emails) method of a Rails mailer, I wish to perform some logging.

My method looks like this:

```
def receive(email)
  logger.warn "Now receiving e-mail..."
  # do stuff
end
```

Everything works just fine, I can receive e-mails and do stuff with them. However, I do not see any logged output, neither in `logs/production.log` nor in `/var/log/syslog` (this is on a Linux machine).

When I interact with the app via HTTP requests, logging works just fine.

How can I log from the `#receive` method of a Rails mailer?

Answer (score 0):

[Set logging levels in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180690/set-logging-levels-in-ruby-on-rails)

Have you set your logger level to include warnings? If you have and you're still having issues try:

```
config.logger.level = Logger::WARN
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the question, logging does work as expected and with all levels that I want to see, as long as I interact with the app in a browser. The `#receive` method is called via `rails runner` which in turn is invoked by a Postscript transport.