# I need help re-writing 2 DB Queries that were originally written with a gem called squeel

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

I re-wrote the 2 DB queries, they don't give a syntax error but they give me an error on array which is telling me I must not have them written properly.

They were originally written with this gem called squeel which uses it own DSL to make queries simpler (I think that is debatable).

Squeel no longer works, as a result I have an APP with DB queries that will not function properly.  I have been able to re-write most of them, but a few of them in this app are complicated (to me at least).

Here is DB query 1 in it's original squeel state:

```
if donaldson_primary?
  Project.joins{vendor}.joins{certifications.outer}
  .where{(projects.vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) | 
  (vendors.parent_vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) | 
  ((certifications.donaldson == true) & (certifications.published == 
  true))}.uniq
```

Here is my re-write of DB query 1

```
if donaldson_primary?
  Project.joins(:vendor).left_outer_joins(:certifications)
  .where(projects: {vendor_id: vendor_id })
  .or(Project.joins(:vendor).left_outer_joins(:certifications)
  .where(projects: {parent_vendor_id: vendor_id}))
  .or(certifications.donaldson == true)
  .and(certifications.published == true).uniq
```

Here is DB query 2 in it's original squeel state:

```
elsif cdti_primary?
  Project.joins{vendor}.joins{certifications.outer}
  .where{(projects.vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) |
  (vendors.parent_vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) |
  ((certifications.cdti == true) 
  & (certifications.published == true))}.uniq
```

Here is my re-write DB query 2:

```
elsif cdti_primary?
  Project.joins(:vendor).left_outer_joins(:certifications)
  .where(projects: {vendor_id: vendor_id})
  .or(Project.joins(:vendor).left_outer_joins(:certifications)
  .where(projects: {parent_vendor_id: vendor_id }))
  .or(certifications.cdti == true)
  .and(certifications.published == true).uniq
```

I am not sure if I am re-writing the queries right, I have never had a joins that combines a join and an outer join in the same JOIN.  When I looked up the docs for squeel the .outer refers to a left_outer_join which is why I tried to use join and left_outer_join together.

Here is a link to the instructions for squeel.
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel

If anyone can let me know if I have the queries right that would be helpful and if not where I went wrong.  These are more complicated than I have dealt with so far with the combining join and outer joins at the same time, I believe I understand what the original writer of the code was trying to do, just not sure I am telling Rails the same way or not.

I am also wondering if it wouldn't be easier to just write them with where(pure sql code) vs using Active Record.  I don't know if there is a consequence to doing it that way or not?

I found out a way to get the SQL info requested.
Fortunately this was in production.rb

```
config.logger.level = Logger.const_get(
    ENV['LOG_LEVEL'] ? ENV['LOG_LEVEL'].upcase : 'INFO'
```

So I added an ENV called LOG_LEVEL and put DEBUG as the value.

I originally posted the WRONG SQl, the SQL I had captured was from the DES SQL which was the WRONG SQL, didn't realize this at first.  I figured it out and now I have captures the CORRECT SQL.

Here is the CDTI SQL:

```
2021-09-28T18:34:09.725811+00:00 app[web.1]: Project Load (0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."vendor_id" = 27 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
2021-09-28T18:34:09.727528+00:00 app[web.1]: CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "projects"."id") FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."vendor_id" = 27
2021-09-28T18:34:09.749837+00:00 app[web.1]: Vendor Load (5.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" INNER JOIN "certifications" ON "certifications"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE (("certifications"."cdti" = 't' AND "certifications"."published" = 't')) ORDER BY "vendors"."parent_vendor_id", "vendors"."name"
```

Here is the Donaldson SQL

```
2021-09-28T18:30:18.061204+00:00 app[web.1]: CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "projects"."id") FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."vendor_id" = 3
2021-09-28T18:30:18.119863+00:00 app[web.1]: Vendor Load (7.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" INNER JOIN "certifications" ON "certifications"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE (("certifications"."donaldson" = 't' AND "certifications"."published" = 't')) ORDER BY "vendors"."parent_vendor_id", "vendors"."name"
2021-09-28T18:30:18.481748+00:00 app[web.1]: Fleet Load (348.1ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "fleets".* FROM "fleets" INNER JOIN "vendors" ON "vendors"."id" = "fleets"."vendor_id" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" INNER JOIN "certifications" ON "certifications"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE (("certifications"."donaldson" = 't' AND "certifications"."published" = 't')) ORDER BY "fleets"."vendor_id", "fleets"."name"
```

I made another attempt at re-writing the 2 queries, here is what I came up with, if anyone knows where I am going wrong I would LOVE the input.

Query 1:

```
if donaldson_primary?
      Project.joins(:vendor, :certifications).where(projects: {vendor_id: vendor_id })
      .or(Project.joins(:vendor, :certifications).where(projects: {parent_vendor_id: vendor_id}))
      .or(certifications.donaldson == true).and(certifications.published == true).uniq
```

Query 2:

```
elsif cdti_primary?
      Project.joins(:vendor, :certifications).where(projects: {vendor_id: vendor_id})
      .or(Project.joins(:vendor, :certifications).where(projects: {parent_vendor_id: vendor_id }))
      .or(certifications.cdti == true).and(certifications.published == true).uniq
```

I know I don't have the syntax right, I am really trying but struggling with this.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the SQL output and what the expected result is. From a glance the Squeel query looks ludicrisly overcomplicated. Like job security overcomplicated.

Comment: This app is currently running on Heroku on an outdated version of Ruby on Rails, I am trying to re-write it to the current version as they are going to do a forced DB Upgrade on PostgreSQL and when that happnes it will break the app.  I had to re-write another app called Ctrlpanel already after it was broken due to the forced DB upgrade.  The logs on Heroku isn't showing the SQL?  Even when I use the --tails command, do you know how I can get Heroku to display the SQL?  It just skips that part for some reason.

Comment: Depends slightly on the version of Rails - on Rails 4+ you set `config.log_level = :debug` in `config/environments/production.rb`.  The log levels for production are higher by default as logging slows the app down. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180690/set-logging-levels-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Slight issue, Heroku will not let me modify the code at all because it is on an older stack and an outdate version of Ruby on Rails.  I can't get a similar environment to run on anything, not Linux, not Windows, nothing.  You just gets error after error about dependencies issues.  I ran into this when CtrlPanel went down and spent almost a MONTH trying to get Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails v4.2.1 to run on anything anywhere and it just wouldn't work.  Is there a way I can at the console on Heroku start the app in a way that will display the SQL?

Comment: Emissions Gateway is currently running on Heroku using Ruby 2.0.0 and rails 3.2.18

Comment: Where does this code live? The model? Controller? Elsewhere?

Comment: I added the entire user.rb model file which is where those 2 queries sit.  You can also see the scopes I also redid as well.  I was so excited when I thought hey I can just go grab the SQL since i can see it in the console, then I could have just use the strait SQL, sigh... if it was only that simple, ggrrr.  I am still new to rails.  I am surprised there isn't a log or console output that shows the SQL in production mode without having to modify the code itself.  That would make it so much easier.

Comment: If the method returns an ActiveRecord::Relation or AssociationProxy or similiar you can call `.to_sql` on it to dump the SQL. This doesn't work if you have used any methods like `.uniq` which returns an array instead. You might be able to toggle the logger debug level from the console with `Rails.logger.level = :debug`.

Comment: @max for an AR Relation `uniq` was an alias for `distinct` however it was deprecated in 5.0 in favor of explicit `distinct`. OP this `projects: {parent_vendor_id: vendor_id}` should be `vendors: {parent_vendor_id: vendor_id}`

Comment: @engineersmnky good point. Thanks. I had this feeling that there was something off about `.uniq` but it must have gotten mixed in up my foggy memory with the rest of the enumerable methods. 5.0 feels like it sooo long ago.

Comment: I found a way to get the SQL!  Let me know if this helps to figure out if I have the 2 queries right, I am assuming no by what I am reading but I am trying to figure it out.  If not I might be able to use the strait SQL right with a where(strait sql) ?  What is confusing me is I don't see an outer join like I thought I understood from the Squeel docs.  man I need to get better with SQL!

Comment: @max I found the SQL if you have a moment I would love your thoughts on those 2 queries I am trying to re-write, I have been trying off and on but I am not having much luck mostly because I don't know the correct syntax to chain joins together.

Comment: @max, I apologize I originally captured the DES SQL which the methods for that is already working, took me a while to figure out HOW to get the CDTI and DONALDSON SQL and Now I am sure I have the RIGHT SQL.  If you get any time I would appreciate your insight, I know I don't have the last part of the syntax right where I am looking for the certification.cdti and certification.published to equal true,  trying to figure out how to do it.