# Need assistance re-writing some Rails DB Queries that were originally written with a gem called Squeel, have the working SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have a couple really hard DB queries I need help to re-write in the correct way for Rails 6 Active Record.  These are currently working in an app I an re-writing to the new version of Ruby on Rails (6.1.4.2).

It was originally written on Rails v3.2 with a Hell gem called squeel which uses its own DSL Language.

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel

I have been trying for days now and haven't been able to get it figured out.  The first time I asked it I probably wasn't as clear as I needed to be.  So this time I am going to put the query as it was written in squeel, and the SQL that the console from Heroku is spitting out and that's all.  If anyone wants any additional information ask and I will HAPPILY post it.  I want to keep it simple to start with as they are confusing enough.

WARNING: These seem to be EXTREMLY COMPLICATED.
ANY HELP would be VERY Appreciated! :)

Here is squeel DB Query 1:

```
Project.joins{vendor}.joins{certifications.outer}.where{
        (projects.vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) |
        (vendors.parent_vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) |
        ((certifications.cdti == true) & (certifications.published == true))
      }.uniq
```

Here is the strait SQL from query 1 out of Rails v3.2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" 
INNER JOIN "certifications" ON "certifications"."project_id" = "projects"."id" 
WHERE (("certifications"."cdti" = 't' AND "certifications"."published" = 't')) 
ORDER BY "vendors"."parent_vendor_id", "vendors"."name"
```

Here is the squeel DB query 2:

```
Fleet.joins{vendor.projects.certifications}.
        where{(certifications.cdti.eq true) & (certifications.published.eq true)}.
        uniq.includes(:vendor).
        order(:vendor_id, :name)
```

Here is the strait SQL from query 2 out of Rails v3.2:
(I hit enter in a few places so you could see the entire statement without having to scroll to the right

```
SELECT DISTINCT "fleets".* FROM "fleets" INNER JOIN "vendors" ON "vendors"."id" = "fleets"."vendor_id" 
INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" 
INNER JOIN "certifications" ON "certifications"."project_id" = "projects"."id" 
WHERE (("certifications"."cdti" = 't' AND "certifications"."published" = 't')) 
ORDER BY "fleets"."vendor_id", "fleets"."name"
```

Again if anyone wants to see or know anything else just let me know as I am trying my best to figure this out, but these seem so advanced I just don't think I know the correct syntax.

Thank You for your time,
Scott

Comment: According to your SQL, I guess that query 1 is: `Vendor.joins(projects: :certifications).where(certifications: { cdti: 't', published: 't' }).order(:parent_vendor_id, :name).distinct`. Could you check if that generates the correct SQL query?

Comment: Also, query 2 is maybe equivalent to this: `Fleet.joins(vendors: { projects: :certifications }).where(certifications: { cdti: 't', published: 't' }).order(:vendor_id, :name).distinct`. Let me know if any of them help. If so, I'll write the answer

Comment: @JoãoFernandes,  I am getting an error: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError at /projects
Can't join 'Fleet' to association named 'vendors'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: I have been trying to join JUST Fleets to Vendors and I haven't even been able to make that work just the two.  If you need to see the 3 models for the associations let me know. I believe query 1 worked, it got past it as far as I can tell.

Comment: THIS WORKED!:  Fleet.joins(vendor: { projects: :certifications })
      .where(certifications: { cdti: 't', published: 't' })
      .order(:vendor_id, :name).distinct   (I just chanded vendors to vendor)

Comment: `Fleet` and `Vendor` is a `has_one` association? If so, you may have to change from `vendors:` to `vendor`

Comment: I had tired just that while you were typing that, you are the MAN!  I am so thankful you have no idea how much of a BEAR those 2 queries have been, I have been getting up at 5 AM and watching any video I could find on Active Record Join examples.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1 equivalent is:

```rb
Vendor.joins(projects: :certifications).where(certifications: { cdti: 't', published: 't' }).order(:parent_vendor_id, :name).distinct
```

Query 2:

```rb
Fleet.joins(vendor: { projects: :certifications }).where(certifications: { cdti: 't', published: 't' }).order(:vendor_id, :name).distinct
```

Comment: I did not understand that if it is using a has_one / belongs_to association you have to use :vendor, vs :vendorS.  HARD Lesson, I will not forget it. :)  That little S cost me SO much time!  Thank You again @João Fernandes

Comment: I had posted this question a different way before, this is essentially the same answer if you want to answer this you can.  Otherwise I will write the answer when I have them correct and working but without you I couldn't have done it.      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272014/i-need-help-re-writing-2-db-queries-that-were-originally-written-with-a-gem-call